# How many senators approved the change to the cloture rule in 1975?

Tags: united-states, senate, senate-rules

According to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/did-the-senate-break-their-own-rules-by-invoking-the-nuclear-option/2396#2396), only a simple majority is needed to change the Senate's rules not a supermajority.

> Ordinarily, a point of order compels the Senate to follow its rules and precedents; however, the Senate may choose to vote down the point of order. when this occurs, a new precedent is established [...]

Before this, the previous [change to the cloture rule occurred in 1975]<sup>Broken link removed</sup>, when the Senate reduced the requirement for cloture on all matters *except* future rules changes:

> Before 1975, two-thirds of the Senators present and voting (a quorum being present) was required for cloture on all matters. In early 1975, at the beginning of the 94th Congress, Senators sought to amend the rule to make it somewhat easier to invoke cloture. However, **some Senators feared that if this effort succeeded, that would only make it easier to amend the rule again, making cloture still easier to invoke**. As a compromise, the Senate agreed to move from two-thirds of the Senators duly chose and sworn (normally, and at a maximum, 60 votes) on all matters **except future rules changes, including changes in the cloture rule itself**.

**How many senators approved the amendment to the cloture rule in 1975?** (i.e. was it 2/3rds, 3/5ths, a simple majority)

*See*: [Changing the Senate Cloture Rule at the Start of a New Congress](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R44709.pdf) for more recent information, including reference to the change in 1975.

Answer (score 2):

**The amendment to the cloture rule (Rule XXII) was approved by a two-thirds supermajority, 56-27**

In 1975 the Senate followed their rules in passing [S.RES.4: Resolution to amend Rule XXII of the Standing Rules of the Senate](https://www.congress.gov/bill/94th-congress/senate-resolution/4). The resolution passed 3/7/1975:

> Measure passed Senate, amended, roll call #55 (56-27) (Provisions of S.Res. 93 included in passage).

Comment: The "nuclear option" followed the rules of the Senate - it just followed a convoluted path through those rules, rather than the straightforward one.  It's also entirely irrelevant to answering the question as asked.

Comment: @Bobson, I disagree with that interpretation and so does Senator Reid, former senator Biden, former senator Obama, [...]. While the Senate can set a new precedent, they can only do so by **not following the previous rules**. Why do you think they ask the parlitarian, "what is the rule?" (I call that breaking them, you call it bypassing them potatoe=potato). Do you think it is possible to set a **new precedent**, by following your original agreed to rules/procedures? I can't understand the kind of tortured logic necessary to believe that.

Comment: See my answer to your other question.  The rule *specifically* only affected cloture votes related to changing it.  **The rule was changed without a cloture vote.  Therefore, the rule was not "broken".**   It's equivalent to the SE set of rules: "You can't upvote your own question.  If your question is edited enough, it becomes community wiki.  You can upvote community wiki questions.  Therefore, under a specific set of circumstances, you can upvote your own question without violating the rule on upvoting your own questions."

Comment: If you want to call it "broken", you can.  It certainly violates the *intent* of the rule and "breaks" it in the sense that it no longer has meaning.  But if it truly violated the actual rule, it wouldn't have any force.  I'll go edit my other answer to clarify terminology.

Comment: Side thought: I suggest removing the bias from this answer as per [your own meta suggestion](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/do-you-want-to-help-politics-se-we-need-your-help-in-suggesting-neutral-wording).

Comment: @Bobson - better? Of course, it was truth, not bias, but even that's gone now.

Comment: @DVK It wasn't truth at all.  The Senate did not violate any rules, as Bobson points out in his answer.

Comment: @DVK - Yes, it's better now - my thanks to Keshav.  It's irrelevant whether or not it was truth - the actions of the Senate in 2013 have nothing to do with the results of a vote in in 1975.  Including it added nothing useful to the answer.  I'd have edited it out myself, but I'm trying to refrain from editing user1873.

Comment: @Bobson - and yet, the voting pattern is the same after the edit. Which leads me to believe that it does indeed have nothing to do with "bias" of the poster, and merely of the voters

Comment: @DVK - The answer is now on-point to the question, so I've already changed *my* vote from a downvote to an upvote.  I can't speak for anyone else.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but how is 56 votes a 2/3rd super majority when there are 100 total possible votes?