# Is there a place to find the "unofficial" Senate rules?

Tags: united-states, senate, senate-rules

I was able to find the "official" Senate rules [here](https://www.rules.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=RulesOfSenateHome).  However, it seems that the Senate sometimes changes the rules without changing these official rules.  For example, they changed the judicial filibuster rule as laid out in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/2396/13366) - but since they never officially changed the rules with a 2/3 majority as required, the "rule" they are now using isn't listed in those official rules.

This is a little annoying when trying to discuss Senate rules.  Is there a place to find these rules that weren't passed by 2/3, yet the Senate still uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a document called [Riddick's Senate Procedure](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-RIDDICK-1992) that contains this sort of thing.  Unfortunately, it seems the most recent edition is from 1992,  and therefore it would not contain, for example, the new filibuster rules.

I was also able to find the [Senate manual](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/SMAN-113/pdf/SMAN-113.pdf) from 2014.  This contains a section on "Nonstatutory standing orders not embraced in the rules".  There was an order in there titled "To provide for expedited Senate consideration of certain nominations subject to advice and consent", but this did not appear to be the new filibuster rule.  Given that the rule was first reinterpreted in late 2013, it's possible that it simply did not make it into this edition.

A document titled "[Senate Consideration of Presidential Nominations: Committee and Floor Procedure](https://www.senate.gov/CRSpubs/74919ab6-b407-451c-b429-702e9ae8dcb1.pdf)" from the Congressional Research Service notes that the rule has been reinterpreted, but the citation is to the congressional record of the day the rule was interpreted, which isn't all that helpful for finding similar rule interpretations (unless you feel like scouring the entire congressional record.)