# What makes the "Nuclear Option" in the US Senate a precedent that its chair has to uphold?

Tags: united-states, senate, senate-rules

Let me first sum up what the nuclear option is, as far as I understand it : a cloture vote happens, carrying more than half of the votes but less than the required supermajority. Pursuant to the written rules of the Senate, the chair announces that the cloture vote fails. A senator makes a point of order invoking a rationale not written in the senate rules. The chair rules against that point of order. An appeal is made on that ruling, and is ruled on by a majority of the senators (potentially with the VP tie-break). The ruling is overturned and the cloture is invoked.

It makes sense that the "thing" on which cloture gets invoked (let's say the nomination of Neil Gorsuch to the Supreme Court for example) does get the cloture, as the Senate as a whole ruled that way. But how and why would the rationale invoked by the Senator raising the point of order (here, that SCOTUS nominations' clotures are by simple majority vote) be kept for *future* rulings, as it contradicts the written rules of the Senate ? Why is that rationale considered a more important precedent than the rules ? Do the written rules say that an overruling of the chair does such precedent ?

Further question, assuming such thing is not part of the written rules. What would happen if a future chair (let's say the president pro tem, with the VP not present but agreeing with them) decides to only uphold the written rules of the Senate, accepting individual challenges of the ruling of the chair but rejecting the idea that such challenges create precedents ? What would they violate, apart from the opinion of the parliamentarian ?

NB : it may seem that this is a partly theoretical question, in part due to the very partisan nature of senate chairing and rules enforcing. However, there are a lot of people, among which the senators themselves, who recognize these precedents as real existing things. In particular, there have been a lot of judicial nominations since Reid's nuclear option and several SCOTUS nominations since McConnell's, and in all cases the chair applied the precedent as created (apparently) by the nuclear option. Instead of requiring individual overrulings of the chair for individual nominations, for example.

Comment: I think https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/did-the-senate-break-their-own-rules-by-invoking-the-nuclear-option?rq=1 answer your question.  Specifically the senate voted specifically that overruling the chair does create precedent.

Comment: Once one party uses it, the other party is going to use it to "get even". *Legal* precedent is irrelevant.

Comment: @JamesK so you're saying that McConell's PoO, being defeated, made Reid's PoO a precedent ?

Comment: I'm saying that this precise question was raised in the senate and answered.

Comment: @JamesK When and how did that happen, then, if not by rejecting McConnell's point of order ? And if so, what leads you (and 2391's answer... ish) to conclude that *this* specifically created the precedent ? The answer to the question you linked vaguely asserts that in the summary of what happened but does not expand or explain it.

Comment: McConnell point of order didn't create the precedent.  It answered the question "does overruling the chair create precedent?"  But this is angels on a pinhead type discussion.  Did an unwritten rule exist before the situation that the rule enforces has arisen?

Comment: @JamesK So, you're saying that if Reid's PoO was passed but McConnell's *also* passed, it would have created the one-time challenge situation I'm referring to in the last paragraph of the question ? This may be partly a theoretical question, but a lot of people are stating as a matter of fact that the precedent was indeed created. And the behavior of the chair in all judicial nominations subsequent to the nuclear options being inkoved did use that precedent, and did not involve individual nuclear options being used for each single nomination.

Comment: The chair ruled that "UNDER THE PRECEDENT SET BY THE SENATE TODAY, THE THRESHOLD FOR CLOTURE ON NOMINATIONS, NOT INCLUDING THOSE OF THE SUPREME COURT OF UNITED STATES, IS NOW A MAJORITY" McConnell challenged this, the senate voted and confirmed the opinion of the chair.  If the McConnel vote had gone the other way it would have left a strange paradoxical situation, and I don't know how it would have sorted itself out.  (apologies for all caps, it is in the source)

Comment: the sequence is as described "Reid made a point of order, that cloture for appointments is by simple majority", "Chair ruled, 'It's not'" "Reid asked for roll call vote on this ruling" "Senate voted that the chair was wrong".  "Chair ruled 'A new precedent has been set'" "McConnell asked for a roll call"  "Senate voted that the  chair was correct".

Comment: It's still unclear, because McConnell did not say anything other than "I object to the ruling", so if his PoO were sustained, would it invalidate the first part of the sentence up to the first comma, and only make it non-binding precedent, or rather the second part of the sentence, and serve as a "motion to reconsider" Reid's appeal ? Or both at the same time ? Anyway, since his PoO failed, I'd range to your opinion : it seems that Leahy pulled the "precedent" thing a bit out of his hat, but the failure of McConnell's appeal sanctified it. Anyway, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a precedent that the chair has to uphold because the Senate says so.

When the "nuclear option" was first used, to allow cloture on appointments by simple majority this question was asked of the Chair.  The chair gave the opinion (presumably on advice of the Parliamentarian) that upholding the point of order did indeed create a new precedent (and announced that fact to the Senate).  This opinion was challenged and put to a roll call vote. The senate voted (52-48) that a new precedent had indeed been set.

The precedent becomes part of the rules of the Senate.

Now suppose in future there is a cloture vote on an appointment, and it passes 52-48 (say) If the chair rules that this isn't enough there would be a point of order and the 52 votes would again overrule the chair. This is why it is a "nuclear option", it is difficult to modify this precedent and re-establish the 60 vote requirement, as whenever a point of order could arise, there would always be majority short term interest in maintaining the precedent.

Comment: I think there's a very interesting thing about the democrats (in this example) wanting to make a bogus point of order, make it be refused by the democratic pro tempore, and then overridden by the senators, rather than having the pro tempore voluntarily misdeclaring the cloture vote as successful, the republicans making a (valid) point of order against that, and the bogus ruling of the chair being upheld by the senate. Both would amount to the same in terms of rules, but they always decided to do the one over the other. Fascinating.